# Define WADL resources base in Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey, wadl

I am using Jersey 1.9 and it is generating my WADL perfectly except I need to redefine the resources base URI.

I'm running Jetty 7 sitting behind Apache using mod_proxy as a reverse proxy to route REST requests back to Jetty / Jersey. So Jersey generates the resources base URI as

`http://localhost:8080/testRestAPI/rest/`

when I need something like

`http://mydomain.com/rest/`

I found this from Google but it is not working: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Changing-baseURI-when-generating-WADL-td6169703.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, you've found a bug in Jersey implementation. Please file a new issue as stated on mailing list - jira link: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY

What you can do for now is downgrade to Jersey 1.8, which should not be affected by latest changes in this area. Thanks and sorry for inconvenience!

EDIT: issue link: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-773

it is already fixed, so you should be able to use this feature in Jersey 1.10-b02 and newer.

Comment: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-775 is a duplicate of http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-773 :) which has been already filed and fixed by Marek.

Comment: Wow! Someone beat me to it. What a nice project and active community.